# Find $P(4 \leq X^2+Y^2 \leq 9)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent uniformly distributed random variables with $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}Y=0$ and $\mathbb{D}X=\mathbb{D}Y=4$. The task is to find following probability:
$$P(4\leq (X^2+Y^2) \leq 9)$$
P.S: Here $\mathbb{D}$ stands for variance.

I've tried the following:

Let's find $\varphi_{X^2+Y^2}(t)=(\varphi_X^2(t))^2$
$\varphi_X^2(t)=...=\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{8-it}}$, so $\varphi_{X^2+Y^2}(t)=\cfrac{1}{1-8it}$, and that leads us to: $X^2+Y^2 \sim \text{Exp}(\frac{1}{8})$.

And so on.
However I was told that this solution is not correct and there is more efficient and smart one. May you help me?

Comment: Please fix the problems in the text. What is $\Bbb D$? Which is the result after the "and so on" in the OP?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: @dan_fulea fixed that. Sorry.

Comment: @P.J. fixed that. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably $\mathbb{D}X$ is the variance.

The problem is very simple. If you do a drawing, the requested probability is the probability of  an annulus resulting as the difference of the two disks, the greater with radius $3$ and the inner with radius $2$

Knowing mean and variance you can calculate $f_X$ and $f_Y$

Thus the solution is simply the purple area multiplied by the joint density or, what is the same, the purple area divided by the total area of the square.

[image]

---

If I assumed correctly $\mathbb{D}$ as Variance, easy find that

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-2\sqrt{3};2\sqrt{3})}(x)$$

thus the requested probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[4\leq X^2+Y^2\leq 9]=\frac{1}{16\cdot3}(9-4)\pi\approx 32.72\%$$

Comment: And may you write your calculations in a more detailed way, please.

Comment: @James : the requested probability is the ara of the purple annulus divided by the area of the total square. 

Area of the purple annulus: 

$$a=\pi\cdot3^2-\pi\cdot2^2$$

Area of the total square:

$$A=(4\sqrt{3})^2$$

Result: $\frac{a}{A}$

Now I think it is clear

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.